# Extjs: How to separate sites for mobile and desktop web app using extjs

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I've read some old questions from this stack about separate sites for mobile & desktop app like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813045/single-code-base-for-mobile-and-desktop-app), but it's about suggested technology. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286522/sencha-touch-extjs-profiles-for-desktop-and-mobile-in-one-web-project-vhost) it's "almost" same question but no answers and still different. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132953/same-sencha-app-for-web-and-mobile) question really useful for me, and etc. But I want to ask a bit different question about separate sites for mobile and desktop app.

Here's my problem :
 1. As @Juned-ahsan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26133010/2735482), it's about looks and contents to be displayed. So, I think i can create separate sites for mobile and desktop app using one MVC structure for both. Can I ?
This is my MVC structure for development :

```
htdocs/myapp
         |- application   //This's my CI MVC
             |- controllers
             |- models
             |- views
                  |- v_desktop.php   // View for DESKTOP extjs4
                  |- v_login.php     // View for Login Page
                  |- v_mobile.php    // View for MOBILE touch2
         |- ext           //This's my Extjs 4.2 src
         |- touch         //This's my Sencha touch 2 src
         |- extapp        //This's my Extjs MVC
             |- app
                  |- controller
                  |- model
                  |- store
                  |- view
             |- applogin  //
                  |- controller
                  |- view
                  |- applogin.js
             |- app.js
         |- touapp        //This's my touch MVC
              |- controller
              |- model
              |- profile
              |- store
              |- view
              |- app.js
         |- system        //This's my CI MVC
         |- temp
```

2. How to load **dynamically** mobile & desktop sites from one page ? My current solution is using user_agents to detect the browsers and one page for each mobile & desktop just like my structure tell. May be somebody have another trick to load mobile & desktop app just using one page ?
3. I think about a tricky way just like how to dynamically change a themes between neptune, classic, etc in Extjs like [This](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#all), for the dynamically load a mobile or desktop web app.

Please suggest how can I achieve that, or any other way to do that ?